# Flycheck checker python-flake8 returned non-zero exit code 1, but its output contained no errors

Tags: python, flycheck

Hello I'm having trouble while trying to use `flake8` and `flycheck`, I know this probably this isn't a issue with `flycheck` per se but I need some guidance about what is happening.

#### The problem

On a python file when I run `flycheck-buffer` I get this error:

```
Suspicious state from syntax checker python-flake8: Flycheck checker python-flake8 returned non-zero exit code 1, but its output contained no errors: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lcl/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/ticket/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flake8/checker.py", line 501, in run_ast_checks
    ast = self.processor.build_ast()
  File "/Users/lcl/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/ticket/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flake8/processor.py", line 211, in build_ast
    return compile(''.join(self.lines), '', 'exec', PyCF_ONLY_AST)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udcc3' in position 1850: surrogates not allowed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lcl/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/ticket/bin/flake8", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/lcl/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/ticket/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flake8/main/cli.py", line 16, in main
    app.run(argv)
  File "/Users/lcl/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/ticket/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flake8/main/application.py", line 322, in run
    self._run(argv)
  File "/Users/lcl/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/ticket/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flake8/main/application.py", line 306, in _run
    self.run_checks()
  File "/Users/lcl/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/ticket/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flake8/main/application.py", line 244, in run_checks
    self.file_checker_manager.run()
  File "/Users/lcl/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/ticket/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flake8/checker.py", line 350, in run
    self.run_serial()
  File "/Users/lcl/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/ticket/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flake8/checker.py", line 334, in run_serial
    checker.run_checks(self.results_queue, self.statistics_queue)
  File "/Users/lcl/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/ticket/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flake8/checker.py", line 606, in run_checks
    self.run_ast_checks()
  File "/Users/lcl/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/ticket/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flake8/checker.py", line 504, in run_ast_checks
    row, column = self._extract_syntax_information(exception)
  File "/Users/lcl/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/ticket/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flake8/checker.py", line 476, in _extract_syntax_information
    if column > 0 and token and isinstance(exception, SyntaxError):
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()

Try installing a more recent version of python-flake8, and please open a bug report if the issue persists in the latest release.  Thanks!
```

Now the pointed position is just a word with an accented character in the document block of a function. But that's not my problem here, because when I run `flake8` on the file from my zshell it works just fine.

#### What I've tried

A lot of related issues suggest updating `flake8` but as of today I have the most recent version:

```
~ ❯ flake8 --version
3.2.1 (mccabe: 0.5.3, pycodestyle: 2.2.0, pyflakes: 1.3.0) CPython 3.6.0 on Darwin
```

Within emacs using `M-: (process-lines "flake8" "--version")` this is recognized as well:

```
("3.2.1 (pyflakes: 1.3.0, mccabe: 0.5.3, pycodestyle: 2.2.0) CPython 3.5.2 on Darwin")
```

Another similar issues on internet suggest there's something wrong with the environment, and that could be the problem but in this case I'm not so sure since `flake8` on emacs works without issues, only flycheck fails.

This is the `flycheck-verify-setup` output:

```
Syntax checkers for buffer views.py in python-mode:

  python-flake8
    - may enable:         yes
    - executable:         Found at /Users/lcl/.pyenv/shims/flake8
    - configuration file: Not found

  python-pylint
    - may enable:         yes
    - executable:         Found at /usr/local/bin/pylint
    - configuration file: Not found

  python-pycompile
    - may enable: yes
    - executable: Found at /Users/lcl/.pyenv/shims/python

The following checker is explicitly selected for this buffer:

  python-flake8
    - major mode:         `python-mode' supported
    - may enable:         yes
    - executable:         Found at /Users/lcl/.pyenv/shims/flake8
    - configuration file: Not found

Flycheck Mode is enabled.  Use M-x universal-argument C-c ! x to
enable disabled checkers.

--------------------

Flycheck version: 31snapshot (package: 20161216.1227)
Emacs version:    25.1.1
System:           x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0
Window system:    mac
```

You can notice that I use `pyenv` I have globally installed `python 3.6.0` and have a `pyenv-virtualenv` with `python 3.5.2` activated, I use `pyenv-mode` to activate the pyenv virtualenv. This virtualenv is the one who has `flake8` installed.

This is my `flycheck-compile` while using the checker `python-flake8`:

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/Documents/nextgen/devel/ticket.dev/nextgen/users/" -*-
Compilation started at Thu Dec 29 00:03:12

/Users/lcl/.pyenv/shims/flake8 --format\=default --stdin-display-name /Users/lcl/Documents/nextgen/devel/ticket.dev/nextgen/users/views.py - < /Users/lcl/Documents/nextgen/devel/ticket.dev/nextgen/users/views.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lcl/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/ticket/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flake8/checker.py", line 501, in run_ast_checks
    ast = self.processor.build_ast()
  File "/Users/lcl/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/envs/ticket/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flake8/processor.py", line 211, in build_ast
    return compile(''.join(self.lines), '', 'exec', PyCF_ONLY_AST)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udcc3' in position 1850: surrogates not allowed
```

We see the same error as I told you but listen to this, if I run `M-x shell` and then copy the same command used by flycheck, it all works fine!

Output in `M-x shell`:

```
/Users/lcl/.pyenv/shims/flake8 --format=default --stdin-display-name /Users/lcl/Documents/nextgen/devel/ticket.dev/nextgen/users/views.py - < /Users/lcl/Documents/nextgen/devel/ticket.dev/nextgen/users/views.py
<panel.dev/nextgen/users/views.py - < /Users/lcl/Documents/nextgen/devel/ticket.dev/nextgen/users/views.py
/Users/lcl/Documents/nextgen/devel/ticket.dev/nextgen/users/views.py:179:5: C901 'UserActions.post' is too complex (19)
/Users/lcl/Documents/nextgen/devel/ticket.dev/nextgen/users/views.py:327:5: C901 'UserUpdateView.form_valid' is too complex (14)
/Users/lcl/Documents/nextgen/devel/ticket.dev/nextgen/users/views.py:507:5: C901 'UserCreateView.form_valid' is too complex (15)
```

I did started to use the [`exec-path-from-shell`](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) package but the error is still happening, what could be happening? **Why is `flycheck` the only missing the party?**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, flake8 gives the error because it doesn't get utf-8 as input. Doing C-h C RET my settings were:

```
Defaults for subprocess I/O:
  decoding: - -- undecided-unix (alias: unix)

  encoding: 1 -- iso-latin-1-unix (alias: iso-8859-1-unix latin-1-unix)
```

Adding `(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)` to .emacs that changed to:

```
Defaults for subprocess I/O:
  decoding: U -- utf-8-unix (alias: mule-utf-8-unix)

  encoding: U -- utf-8-unix (alias: mule-utf-8-unix)
```

Which results in emacs giving the buffer to flake8 as utf-8.

Comment: A lot has changed in my setup, I'm no longer using pyenv and it works well now, but I'm curious, what function does it get called on `C-h C RET`? I don't have the default mappings. Thanks.

Comment: `C-h C` is `describe-coding-system`